# How to search area nearby a location using latitude longitude in elastic search

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I want to search all nearby location given a pair of lat-long through my elastic search which have two separate columns for latitude and longitude.
How to do this

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the geoDistanceQuery. Please find snippet of code below (written in Java, using the Elasticsearch REST High Level Client.

FYI : a complete tutorial is available on my website : [www.ictdynamic.be](https://www.ictdynamic.be) -> ElasticSearch 6 – Spatial Queries with RestHighLevelClient and Java – Part 1: geoDistanceQuery

```
    public Set<?> geoDistanceQuery(String index, String nameGeoPointField, double lat, double lon, double distance, EsQuery esQuery) throws IOException {
    Date startDate = new Date();

    Set<Object> objectsWithinDistance = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();

    QueryBuilder geoDistanceQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders
            .geoDistanceQuery(nameGeoPointField)
            .point(lat, lon)
            .distance(distance, DistanceUnit.KILOMETERS);

    BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = getBooleanQueryWithConditions(esQuery);

    QueryBuilder completeQuery = QueryBuilders
            .boolQuery()
            .must(boolQuery)
            .filter(geoDistanceQueryBuilder);

    sourceBuilder.query(completeQuery).size(SIZE_ES_QUERY);

    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(index)
            .source(sourceBuilder.sort(SortBuilders.geoDistanceSort(nameGeoPointField, lat, lon)
                    .order(SortOrder.ASC)
                    .unit(DistanceUnit.KILOMETERS)));

    SearchResponse searchResponse = restClient.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

    SearchHits hits = searchResponse.getHits();

    for (SearchHit hit : hits.getHits()) {
        objectsWithinDistance.add(GeoService.getObjectFrom_ES_Hit(hit, nameGeoPointField));
    }

    return timedReturn(LOGGER, new Object() {}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName(), startDate.getTime(), objectsWithinDistance);
}
```

Comment: Link's dead. 
https://ictcalimero.wordpress.com/2018/04/06/elasticsearch-6-spatial-queries-with-resthighlevelclient/

https://ictcalimero.wordpress.com/2018/04/22/elasticsearch-6-spatial-queries-with-resthighlevelclient-and-java-part-2-geoboundingboxquery-and-geopolygonquery/